# Parsing json array to array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array with json data:

```
var jsonString=[
  {
    "url": "http://www.anurl.com",
    "tags": {
      "Event": 6,
      "Event1": 2
    }
  }
]
```

Now i want to build the next structure:

```
var data= [ {"text":"Event", "weight" : "6", "link" :"www.anurl.com"} //etc ];
```

Now i looked into the `var array = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(jsonString));`
and on the result i try to build my data array with `.push()`;

But how can i insert the Event: 6 part? i cannot do `array.tags[0]` as array.tags will give me both of them.

So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: can you restructure the Tags JSON or is that out of your control?

Comment: There is no built in solution here, you must manually convert your object into the data object shown. Note that your first example is not a json string, it is merely a JavaScript array with an object in it.

Comment: `jsonString[0].tags.Event` would == `6`

Comment: `var array = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(jsonString));` is completely useless in the context it's used above; `var array= jsonString;` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using object literals in javascript, the example you provided:

```
var jsonString=[{
    "url": "http://www.anurl.com",
    "tags": {
        "Event": 6,
        "Event1": 2
    }
}];
```

`jsonString` is an array, and the element `tags` is an object NOT an array so you can access it like this:

`var event = jsonString[0].tags.Event;`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the attributes of the tags object like the example below :

```js
function loadArray(urls){

 xhrDoc= new XMLHttpRequest();  
 if (xhrDoc.overrideMimeType)
    xhrDoc.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
 xhrDoc.onreadystatechange =function()
 {
  if (this.readyState == 4)
  {
      if (this.status == 200)
     {
      var data= this.response; //Here is a string of the text data 
      printUrls(data);
     }
  }                   
 };
 xhrDoc.open('GET', urls , true);
 xhrDoc.send(); 
}

function printUrls(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "";
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     console.log(arr[i].url);
     console.log(arr[i].tags['Event']); // Read Event 
     console.log(arr[i].tags['Event1']); //// Read Event1

     out = "URL : "+ arr[i].url +  " Event : "+ arr[i].tags['Event']+ " Event1 : " +  arr[i].tags['Event1'] + "\n";
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="parseJsonFile.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="loadArray('parseJson.json')">

<div id="id01"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it with

this code

```
  var array =$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(jsonString));

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
              var keys =array[i].tags;

              var tags = Object.keys(keys);

              for(var j = 0 ; j<tags.length; j++){
                var obj = {text : tags[j], weight : keys[tags[j]] , link : array[i].url};
                  Jarray.push(obj);
              }  


            }
```

The data is provided by an API, so the tag `Event : 6` might be the next time `Tomorrlowland : 3` the name of event and the weight are given by the API. That's why i can't use  `jsonString[0].tags.Event` because the name event will be different every time.

Thanks all for helping me !